# Is there a way to use enterprise library in .NET Core 1.1.2 web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I am planning to use Enterprise Library for database access on a Web API project which is going to be built using .Net core app.
But I am unable to install Enterprise library using NuGet as the latest version of Enterprise Library is not compatible with.Net core app framework.

Note, **I don't want to use Entity Framework**.
Appreciate if the community can help on this.

Comment: It is very likely that you should help yourself instead of waiting for the community. Even if you don't use Entity Framework due to various reasons, many people use, and there are also alternatives, such as Dapper, that support .NET Core.

Comment: I would strongly consider Dapper.  You can still write your own SQL but it handles the tedious part of mapping to objects for you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you can migrate your application to .Net Core 2.0 which is still in preview mode, but [Microsoft promised to release it by Q3 2017](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/roadmap.md), I have forked out the Enterprise Library project and ported that to .Net Core 2.0 which you can find it under this repository:

https://github.com/Chavoshi/EnterpriseLibrary.NetCore

And also this is the Nuget package for Data Application Block:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/EnterpriseLibrary.Data.NetCore

Still there are some missing parts such as [OdbcFactory](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Data.Odbc.OdbcFactory) and [OleDbFactory](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Data.OleDb.OleDbFactory) which they are not available in .Net ported APIs ([Or Nuget package is not published yet](https://github.com/jonwagner/Insight.Database/issues/323)), but I am keep working on them to maybe port them by myself or update it since the API will be available. I appreciate anyone who can contribute on this project as well. :)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I can use .Net Core 2.0 Preview. Let me try this and get back to you.

Comment: Just to inform you, .Net Core 2.0 is already released (EnterpriseLibrary.NetCore packages updated as well)

Comment: You are right Mohammad. I have already installed .Net core 2.0

Comment: Great job! @MohammadChavoshi